# MySQL create new user revoke access to certain DB's

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

So I did created a new user, granted all privilages, and flushed the privilages.
The newly created user can also see the `information_schema`, `mysql`, `performance_schema` and `sys` databases. However, I don't want the user to access those 4. I just want him to have CREATE/DROP/DELETE/INSERT/SELECT (All the required ones), etc permissions on newly created databases.
I did the following:

`CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Answer (score 0):

Run `REVOKE` for the given databases:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON mysql.* FROM 'newuser'@'localhost';
```

I would skip the information_schema revoke. You can see if the user still works without it, but I somehow doubt that.

Answer (score 0):

Privileges: Privileges defines the access rights provided to a user on a database object. There are two types of privileges.

1) System privileges  allows the user to CREATE, ALTER, or DROP database objects.
2) Object privileges  allows the user to EXECUTE, SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE data from database objects to which the privileges apply.

You need to revoke the privilege here you want to remove .Below is the syntax

```
REVOKE privilege_name
ON object_name
FROM {user_name |PUBLIC |role_name}
```